# Multiple Subscriptions to same Subject/Observable on multiple method calls

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, subject

I have a button, upon clicking which, I subscribe to a "data load". Upon successful data load, I have to display a modal.

Here's my code:

Subject and Observable:

```
dataSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
isDataLoaded$: Observable<boolean> = this.dataSubject.asObservable();
```

Fetch Data Method:
(This is a separate method because it is being used in multiple places and not only for populating the modal data.)

```
fetchData() {
  this.dataSubject.next(false);
  ...
  // Fetch Some Data
  ...
  this.dataSubject.next(true);
}
```

Button Click method:

```
buttonClick() {
  // fetch data
  this.fetchData();

  // once the data is loaded, display the modal
  this.dataSubscription = this.isDataLoaded$.subscribe((isDone) => {
    if (isDone) {
      this.displayModal();
    }
  });
}
```

When i click the button the first time it works fine and displays a modal. When I click second or more times, I get multiple instances of the modal pop up. From what I understand, I am subscribing multiple times and hence the multiple modals.
I have also tried unsubscribing before subscribing, to make sure i have a single subscription, but even then I get atleast 2 modals that pop up.

Is the a clean way to implement my requirement? TIA

Comment: Don't you want to call displayModal every time button clicked?

Comment: When / How did you cancel the subscription?

Comment: @abetteroliver I tried it in 2 ways 1) In 'buttonClick' before subscribing, check if subscription exists and unsubscribe. Then subscribe again. 2) In 'displayModal' check if subscription exists and unsubscribe. But neither of these solved my issue

Comment: I'd say the best place to cancel the subscription is right before `if (isDone) {`.

Comment: tried that as well, no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need seperate `isDataLoaded$` I think. Just subscribe to `dataSubject` but not inside `buttonClick`. You trigger the serivce with call to `fetchData` no need subscription to be inside function.

```
this.dataSubscription = this.dataSubject.subscribe((isDone) => {
    if (isDone) {
      this.displayModal();
    }
});

buttonClick() {
  // fetch data
  this.fetchData();
}
```